# Can a UITabBarController be a segue.destinationViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UITabBarController with three tabs: each is a navigation controller with a view controller embedded.  Currently the tabController is the initial view controller. I would like to place an intro view controller with buttons that precedes the tabController, with buttons that segue to the tabController. I'm using Xcode 4.2 and storyboards.

Is this possible?

In my IntroViewController I call prepareForSegue. It is not working:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tabSegue"]) {

    FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc]init];

    self.tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
    UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondVC];
    UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:thirdVC];
    NSArray *tabViewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1,navController2,navController3, nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = tabViewArray;

    }
}
```

In summary, can you segue to a tabBarController?

Comment: Doh! Solved it by putting self.tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController; to the last line.  May my mistake help you out somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment states, I used self.tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController.

Comment: `assignement is read only property` i get that error when using my tabbar Controller

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Ar No**.

My situation was to pass object value from view 1 to 2.

NavControl - ViewController(1)

TabbarControl - NavControl - ViewController(2)